# Почему не запускается секундомер?

Tags: python, kivy

Программа "Секундомер"

Есть класс, начинаюший работу секундомера с помощью import time, но при использовании его в Kivy он начинает лагать. При нажатии на "Старт" программа попросту зависает... Даже представления не имею, в чем дело ? (В консоли, всё работает на "ура")

Вот мой код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyApp(App):

    def update_label(self):
        self.time.text = self.time_start

    def time_start(self,time_start):
        import time
        sec = 0
        min = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            sec += 1
            if sec == 60:
                sec = 0
                min += 1
                self.time_start = "{}:{}".format(min,sec)
            else:
                self.time_start = "{}:{}".format(min,sec)
            self.update_label()


    def build(self):

        gl = GridLayout(cols = 1, padding = 10)
        bl = BoxLayout()


        self.time = Label(text = '0', font_size = 50)


        gl.add_widget(self.time)

        bl.add_widget(Button(text='Старт', font_size = 50, on_press = self.time_start))
        bl.add_widget(Button(text='Круг', font_size = 50))
        gl.add_widget(bl)

        return gl
MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно заменить `self.time_start` на `time_start` и переименовать функцию `time_start` в `start_timer`.

И не нужно давать функциям и переменным одинаковые имена.

Answer (score 0):

Виснет из-за использования конструкции while True.

Нужно использовать Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_label, 1)
Подробнее в документации:https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html

Пример кода для запуска секундомера:

```
def btn_press(self, instance):
    self.sec = 0
    self.minutes = 0
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_lbl, 1)

def update_lbl(self, instance):
    self.sec += 1
    if self.sec == 60:
        self.minutes += 1
        self.sec = 0
    self.time_lbl.text = "{}:{}".format(self.minutes, self.sec)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ответ отредактирован